# document.write update inputs value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, document.write

I'm creating a button that updating inputs' value on different page. I use ajax to get different page content. Next I use jQuery to find appropriate input, change the values and "send it back" via document.wtite(). But then I have jQuery [object object] object on the page instead of page content.

```
  function loadData(container){
      var cont = $(container);
      var loadContainer = cont.find("#first").val();
      loadContainer = "update val";
      return cont;
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      dataType : "html",
      // data: {updateData: formData},
      success: function(res){
          var w = window.open(url, "_blank");
          w.document.write(loadData(res)); //it give me [object object] on the loading page, instead of page content
          w.document.close();
      },
      error: function(xhr, status){
          console.log("error", xhr, status);
      }
  })
```

What is the recommended solution in that's problem?

Comment: You're returning a jQuery object, which when coerced to a string returns `[Object object]`. What exactly are you expecting? The logic doesn't make a great deal of sense as you set `loadContainer` to the string value of the `#first` element, then overwrite that to a static string, then do nothing with it and return the `cont` object...?

Comment: I expecting change small parts of different page - only input value. Whole of this code is call via some button. This button should to redirect you to the different page and update input value on this different page, that in the end you can see this different page with input with updated value.

Comment: no one help? I'm really lost.

Comment: What happens if you comment out loadContainer = "update val"; and change  return cont; to return loadContainer

Comment: Can u put console.log(res) output on the success function

Comment: "no one help?"...Rory gave you quite a lot of help, the code doesn't make much sense, it's hard to understand what you're actually trying to achieve. Give an example of the input and expected output.